# WP Query comment count

Tags: php, wordpress

I use WP_Query to get posts by comment count

```
$aArgs = [
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_type'      => ['post'],
        'paged'   => 1,
        'orderby' => 'comment_count'
    ];
    $oQuery = new \WP_Query($aArgs);
```

All posts that have comment count greater than 0 are ordered correctly. But in some posts(have 0 comment) display in at least 2 pages(Ex:paged=1 and paged=3). I dont know why. Please tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `to maximise your chance of getting an answer`, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. `Update your question` with just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.

Comment: Please reformulate your question and update the code with your full loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see your loop, I can't really guess what is going on... The following script should enable you to loop through posts via the comments count, I just tested it, and it's working on my end.

If I had to guess what is wrong with your script I would say that you probably didn't reset the post data `wp_reset_postdata();` which is probably causing some troubleshoot between pages.

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 20,
  'orderby' => 'comment_count'
) );

if( $query->have_posts() ):
  while( $query->have_posts() ):
    $query->the_post();
    echo the_title() . '<br/>';
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

---

### References

- Learn more about `wp_reset_postdata` @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/